# Cocos2d: accesing child´s from other classes

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, parent-child

Ok! This is the main Scene were I initialize the game, and in the `ParallaxBgTestLayer` there is a class that is added as child of self called `DigBackground` which has a `property` which I want to set from the other layer `gameplayLayer`.

So basically I want to access a child of a child in another class from my `gameplay` layer. What is the preferred way of doing this? Is it even possible to access child of other classes with tags?

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {

        ParallaxBgTestLayer *bgLayer = [ParallaxBgTestLayer node];
        [self addChild:bgLayer z:kParallaxBackgroundLayer];

        DigGameplayLayer *gameplayLayer = [DigGameplayLayer node];
        [self addChild:gameplayLayer z:kGameplayLayer];

    }
    return self;
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing subclasses with properties. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: No... I am using the Cocos2d Framework. Either I create a global singleton to access it or I pass the object to the other classes or, I use the 'add child' memory management in cocos2d

Comment: this explains the possible strategies: http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/Strategies+for+Accessing+Other+Nodes

Comment: Did my below suggestion worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in very simple way:

```
@class ParallaxBgTestLayer;
@class DigGameplayLayer;

@interface MainClass
{
    ParallaxBgTestLayer *bgTestLayer;
    DigGameplayLayer    *gameplayLayer;  
}
@property(monatomic, assign) ParallaxBgTestLayer bgTestLayer;
@property(monatomic, assign) DigGameplayLayer    *gameplayLayer;  
@end

@implementation MainClass

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {

        self.bgLayer = [ParallaxBgTestLayer initWithParent:self];
        [self addChild:self.bgLayer z:kParallaxBackgroundLayer];

        self.gameplayLayer = [DigGameplayLayer initWithParent:self];
        [self addChild:self.gameplayLayer z:kGameplayLayer];

    }
    return self;

}
@end

@interface ParallaxBgTestLayer 
{
    CCNode *parentLayer;
}
@property(monatomic, assign) CCNode *parentLayer;

-(id) initWithParent:(CCNode*)inParent;
@end

@implementation ParallaxBgTestLayer

-(id) initWithParent:(CCNode*)inParent
{
   ParallaxBgTestLayer *obj = [ParallaxBgTestLayer node];
   obj.parentLayer = inParent;
   return obj;
}

-(void)CallMethodInGamePlayLayer
{
   [((DigGameplayLayer*)( (MainClass*)self. parentLayer).gameplayLayer  functionInGamePlayLayer];
}

@end


@interface DigGameplayLayer 
{
    CCNode *parentLayer;
}
@property(monatomic, assign) CCNode *parentLayer;

-(id) initWithParent:(CCNode*)inParent;

@implementation DigGameplayLayer

-(id) initWithParent:(CCNode*)inParent
{
   DigGameplayLayer *obj = [DigGameplayLayer node];
   obj.parentLayer = inParent;
   return obj;
}

-(void) functionInGamePlayLayer
{

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be doing it by using the following steps;

- Update/Override the init method of your DigGameplayLayer in order to get one more parameter ParallaxBgTestLayer
- For example rename your gameplay init method as DigGameplayLayer initOnBackground:(ParallaxBgTestLayer *) backgroundLayer
- import the ParallaxBgTestLayer.h in the implementation file of DigGameplayLayer
- Access to any local variables of ParallaxBgTestLayer (the variables those you added into the ParallaxBgTestLayer.h file)

I think this is better than creating a singleton object if you only need to access from one location. I use singleton when I need them in more than one places in my apps.

I hope, this helps...